# django-paypal change currency to euro

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal

I'm using django-paypal and I want to charge my users in € not in $. I didn't find a way to change that behavior (the currency is always USD). But I'm very sure there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it, just put:

```
"currency_code": "EUR",            # currency
```

in the dictionary.

Comment: Not to be too pedantic, but I believe `currency_code` is deprecated. PayPal now cite `currencycode` in their examples. See https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECSimpleIntegration etc.

Comment: Just for the reader's information: I found that ´currency_code´ is the only parameter that worked for me. (Belgium, EUR currency).

Comment: PayPal [says](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) that `currency_code` is the variable. And it supports [currencies](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/#id09A6G0U0GYK)